# HTML overlapping images

Tags: html, image

I have to place on a web page a cylinder that looks like this:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/33/cylinderl.png/]

it is composed by small images that overlaps to draw the curves on the surface. Every one of them is places on the page with a different img tag enveloped in an anchor with its own href. The z-index property of the img is used to make them overlap in the right way.
The cylinder has to be composed because it is dynamically created, as you can see from the image, its faces can have different colors.

What i need to do is to make all the faces clickable and each one has to point to a different URL.

My problem is, of course, that the cylinder has curves. And i have to be sure that the clicks points to the correct URL especially near the curves, it hasn't to be precise at pixel level, but at least acceptable.

I've tried to use a map with a single area for each of the images that composes the cylinder,  but of course it didn't work, as i saw from the specifications, in such cases only the first declared map in the DOM works.

I'm thinking about to solve this via Javascript, but i think it wouldn't be an easy job, so i would be happy if someone can give me some advice on what should i try.

Oh, i cannot use HTML5 features to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat application of older technology to solve a challenging puzzle.

I can think of two ways forward for you. One is to put a transparent (rectangular) image on top of the cylinder and create an HTML image map, using the `shape="poly"` attribute.  For resources, search for the HTML elements `map` and `area` for reference, especially the `shape` attribute. There should be many good tutorials online. Nowadays this technique isn't used that much any more, but it was really popular in the late 90s.

Another way is to use event delegation in javascript, attaching an event listener to the primary container. On each of your image "pixels" apply a CSS class for the appropriate portion of the cylinder it is in. In your event handler, you can do something differently depending on the class of the clicked on image, and you can do this without the massive overhead of attaching an event on each individual "pixel". In JQuery this would be something like:

```
$("#cylinder").on("click", ".green", function() { location.href = "green_url"; }
$("#cylinder").on("click", ".red", function() { location.href = "red url"; }
```

assuming you put `class="green"` on your green pixels and `class="red"` on your red pixels. (You can do this by quadrant or other technique; color is just an example).

Comment: thanks for the great answer, i think that both ways could solve my problem, tomorrow i'll see :)

Comment: Ok, the transparent image trick did the work :-) thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Your best luck SVG ! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Tutorial
It is almost impossible with html dom elements to do this, you will have to bend it with CSS compatible all browsers.
There is also Canvas but you will have a hard time dealing with the clicks.
Only problem with SVG is that it's not supported in < IE8, and hardly in IE8. But bending a DOM element is also not available < IE9.

EDIT:
I saw that you can't use HTML5, so your only chance is generating the whole image in GD2 for example and trying to map the points. But what is the reason you can't use HTML5 ?

Answer (score 0):

You might also try doing it using javascript / canvas via `getImageData()` function. This canvas function will rgba values of the given point. Using the alpha value you can check if mouse is over or clicking on the correct area or if it is a transparent area and nothing should happen.

I also made jquery plugin exactly for this purpose. Maybe it might help. http://www.cw-internetdienste.de/pixelselection/